# Airflow first DAG not show in UI or dags list

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow and not sure how to create my first DAG. I used Pycharm to create the first DAG_try.py like below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'myname',
    'email': 'myemail',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 4, 29)
}


dag = DAG(dag_id='DAG-try', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once')

Fidelity = BashOperator(task_id='Fidelity_data',
                        bash_command='python Fidelity.py',
                        dag=dag)

Gemini = BashOperator(task_id='Gemini_data',
                      bash_command='python Gemini.py',
                      dag=dag)

Get_results = BashOperator(task_id='get_results',
                           bash_command='python get_results.py',
                           dag=dag)


[Fidelity, Gemini] >> Get_results
```

And put it under the direction C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\username\airflow\dags\

But my DAG is not shown in Airflow UI or in the dags list.

Under the ...\airflow\airflow.cfg file, dags_folder = ~/airflow/dags

I am not sure the direction is setting correctly or not. Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Checkout how to setup airflow on WSL - https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-wsl

Comment: Thanks, I am following the instruction and trying to change the way Windows file system is mounted in Linux. I exactly follow the instruction and change /etc/wsl.conf but I still see /mnt/ in root, not c. Then if I ignore this, rest of the steps will face error. Could you please help know why is this happened?